# elasticsearch client ResponseException - No search context found for id (search_context_missing_exception)

Tags: elasticsearch, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I am using elastic search 6.8.4 with default cluster configuration.
When I execute the gremlin query I get error like this:

```
"message": "method [POST], host [http://es03:9200], URI [/_search/scroll], status line [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found]\n{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"search_context_missing_exception\",\"reason\":\"No search context found for id [36001442]\"}
```

What causes this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
Using the below configuration in elastic search indexing for Janusgraph
    index.search.elasticsearch.create.ext.number_of_shards=5
    index.search.elasticsearch.create.ext.number_of_replicas=2
    index.search.elasticsearch.scroll-keep-alive=600
    index.search.elasticsearch.setup-max-open-scroll-contexts=2000
```